# Infinite page reload on Flask app served using Nginx + Gunicorn

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I am running a Flask app on a DigitalOcean droplet using Gunicorn and Nginx on a Ubuntu 18.04 VPS. I followed [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04) for the setup.

I am facing two strange issues when I access the app from my domain –

1. **The JavaScript elements are either unresponsive or take too long to respond.** This has primarily to do with the buttons that trigger the JS that make Ajax calls and render the results. All other non-Ajax JS runs fine.
2. **On a particular route, the app seems to enter an infinite reload loop.** This has to do with the blueprint I use to display and browse tags. The route - `@tags_bp.route('/<language>/tags/<tag_search>', methods=['GET'])` - renders a template with some responses from server. An allied route - `@tags_bp.route('/<language>/tags/<tag_search>/<variable>', methods=['GET'])` - only returns server responses as JSON that gets rendered on the page.

Interestingly, none of these issues show up when I run the app on localhost (port 5000) using Gunicorn on `<Droplet IP>:5000`. It's only when I access the `<domain>` that the issues occur.

My configuration files are exactly as suggested in [the tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04). I am using a separate server block for my domain instead of the default.

I am suspecting the problem lies somewhere between Nginx and Gunicorn. I tried changing the `headers` in Nginx based on [this page on the Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#proxy-setups) but that didn't help either.

In addition, the site has an SSL certificate issued by Let's Encrypt using certbot.

Any suggestions for how to debug/fix this?

Cheers.

Edit:
The config files are as follows –

**systemmd unit file at `/etc/systemd/system/myproject.service`**

```
[Unit]
Description=Gunicorn instance to serve myproject
After=network.target

[Service]
User=sammy
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/<USER>/myproject
Environment="PATH=/home/<USER>/myproject/myprojectenv/bin"
ExecStart=/home/<USER>/myproject/myprojectenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:myproject.sock -m 007 wsgi:app

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Server block at `/etc/nginx/sites-available/myproject`**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your_domain www.your_domain;

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/<USER>/myproject/myproject.sock;
    }

  # Let's Encrypt credentials ...
}
```

The `nginx.conf` is exactly as the default except that `server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;` is **un-commented**.

Comment: there is clearly more latency in the route to your droplet than on localhost.  you should be using standard methods that ensure js is loaded before any code runs (ie wait until the document has loaded) ... you have not given us enough information to help you solve this question (try providing the actual config files instead of a tutorial link(if you used the exact config files i would imagine the domain is wrong at a minimum), as well as a link to your site so we can see the broken behaviour)

Comment: @JoranBeasley thank you for your inputs! I found a solution to the issues - posted an answer with the fix. You were right about latency.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it with help from some more experienced friends.

The reload loop issue lay in the URL string I was using to make Ajax calls to the database. I was masking the database IDs using the [Python Cryptography](https://cryptography.io/en/latest/) package but that yielded really long strings (~100 characters). This caused some problems with XHR - I don't entirely understand what or how.

I switched instead to creating shorter strings using the `secrets.token_urlsafe(X)` function from the built-in [secrets](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) module in Python.

The first issue had to do with latency as correctly diagnosed by @JoranBeasley. Fixed that by changing the caching technique on the back-end using [Flask Caching](https://flask-caching.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).